# Hide user in Users list using signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am developing a chat application using signalr in asp.net  which is mainly used for customer service now i am facing problem when one operator accepted the client request for private chat this client user should not be displayed for other operators except the operator who accepted, i am struggling to solve this issue

the code i have written in hub class is

i have declared ConnectedUsers as

```
static List<UserDetail> ConnectedUsers = new List<UserDetail>();
```

and added users using

```
ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });
```

and tried to remove private chat users using

```
public void Remove(string UserId, string User)
    {
        UserDetail item = new UserDetail();
        item.ConnectionId = UserId;
        item.UserName = User;
        if (item != null)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

i am calling this code from html page as follows

```
chatHub.server.remove(userId, userName);
```

but this approach is not removing or hiding the user from userlist

Comment: Your code cannot work, since you have never added `item` to `ConnectedUsers`. This is an object you have just created. 
Please add the code where you manage your connected users. Especially where you store them

Comment: Please edit your question and add this piece of information. That's what the edit function is there for.

Answer (score 0):

I would edit edit the `UserDetail` class and add a property `IsAvailable`:

```
public class UserDetail {
    //Guid or string? edit accordingly
    public string ConnectionId { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Per default, each user needs his "IsAvailable" to be true, when he connects.
When they accept a private chat, send a notification to the server that sets IsAvailable to false, for that particular ConnectionId:

```
//you don't really need the user name, id is sufficient
public void Remove(string UserId, string User) {
    var user = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == UserId);
    if(user != null) {
        user.IsAvailable = false;
    }
}
```

That also means, you cannot just return the list of connected users back. But you have to filter it first. So when you push that list to your connected clients, add a where clause `ConnectedUsers.Where(x => x.IsAvailable)`.

That should hide all non-available users on your conncted clients.